# django-notifications not sending any email 

Tags: django, email, notifications

I'm trying to use [django-notification](https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification/) and I can't get it to send any emails. The notifications appears in the Notices, but when I do python manage.py emit_notices this is what I get:

```
acquiring lock...
acquired.
(0.001) SELECT `notification_noticequeuebatch`.`id`, `notification_noticequeuebatch`.`pickled_data` FROM `notification_noticequeuebatch`; args=()
releasing lock...
released.

0 batches, 0 sent
done in 0.00 seconds
```

This is the code sending the Notice:

```
admin = User.objects.get(id=1)
notification.send_now([amin], "order_form_created", {"from_user": admin})
```

Notice settings looks right, my user is subscribed to this kind of notice. From what I understand the app looks in Notification Batches, which are always empty ..

**Edit**: Looks like the problem was the email server .. I used an external SMTP and it worked.

Comment: You can run your own "debugging" email server by executing `python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:10025` in a separate window.  It will simply print out all received emails to that window.

Answer (score 0):

try `notification.queue(..)` instead of `send_now(..)` then python manage.py `emit_notices`

Answer (score -1):

You are doing send_now() so why the emit_notices management command?

Comment: Because `send` didn't work, so I tried with `send_now` .. without any results.